# Insert node in xml using php

Tags: php, xml

I want to insert text node and create element in xml using php
for example

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<employees>
  <employee>
    <name>Albert</name>
    <age>34</age>
    <salary>$10000</salary>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <name>Claud</name>
    <age>20</age>
    <salary>$2000</salary>
  </employee>
</employees>
```

I want insert Data for one more employees using php.

Regards
NewBie

Answer (score 16):

```
<?php 
$xml = simplexml_load_file('clients.xml');
$employee = $xml->addChild('employee');
$employee->addChild('name', 'Claud');
$employee->addChild('age', '20');
$employee->addChild('salary', 'This is all about the people who make it work.');

file_put_contents('clients.xml', $xml->asXML());
```

Comment: what if the XML is held as a variable? oh, its ok: simplexml_load_string. Should've checked first before asking

Answer (score 2):

See the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class documentation. There are examples for XML parsing and modifying.